# Beautiful Soup web scrapping кодировка

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

У меня есть простой скраппер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://dom.ria.com/ru/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8B/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# Remove bottom links

artist_name_list = soup.find_all(class_='wrap_desc')
arr = []
for i in range (len(artist_name_list)):

    name = artist_name_list[i].find(class_='blue')

    main = (name.get_text())

    arr.append(main)
print(arr)
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(arr))
    f.close()
```

он должен читать с сайта и потом заводить в текстовый документ. Он читает но то что я получаю, в странном форматею `print (arr)` выводит чтото типо такого(это не все что он выводит)`‑н.\xa0Соломенский Лебедева-Кумача улица`. Вторая проблема это то что он выдает ошибку

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 22-24: character maps to <undefined>.
```

Я пытался перевести в UTF-8 `arr.encode('utf-8')` но пишет что нельзя. Я пробовал

```
main = (name.get_text().encode('utf-8'))
```

Выходит

```
xbb. \xd0\x9d\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe-\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f
```

Comment: Попробуйте: `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')` -> `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string